# Most computationally efficient way (in terms of RAM, Not storage space) to save many (millions) of varying length numpy arrays in a specific order

Tags: python, numpy

I need save a list containing numpy arrays in a specific order , using the most computationally efficient method. When I mean 'computationally efficient', I mean takes up the least amount of RAM, Not storage space.

For example, would

```
numpy.savez('test.pnz', *listofNumpyArrays)
```

preserve the order of numpy arrays in `listofNumpyArrays` while also spending minimal RAM in the process?

Order is very important because I have another single dimension int array, and each component in that array needs to match with a specific array in `listofNumpyArrays`

I originally put all these numbers into the same numpy variable and it looked like this, with the single int as the fist component of each row, and the corresponding array as the second component of each row (first 10 rows displayed below):

```
array([[0,
        array([10158697,  5255434,  9860860,  3677049,  3451292,  7225330])],
       [1,
        array([ 5985929,  7356938,  5232932,  4623077, 10461651,  6629144,
        2738221,  7672279,  3197654, 11678039,  1912097,  6581279,
        8141689,  6694817,  6139889,  7946369,  3995629,  3169031,
        3793217,  6990097, 11298098,  6120907,  5336712,  7366785,
        7363171,  3933563,  6484209,  4243394,  6371367,  4361218,
       11469370,  6166715, 11519607, 11602639, 10759034,  6432476,
        5327726, 11390220,  7009744, 10225744,  3781058,  1305863,
         462965,  1158562,  2620006,    73896,  4945223, 11780201,
        3044821])],
       [2,
        array([10847593,  8665775,   341568,  4164850,  6509965,  8227738])],
       [3,
        array([ 9105020,  1896456,  2757197,  5911741,  8123078, 10629261,
        5646782,  5255907,  8802504,  3735293,  5496511,  1612181,
       10029269,  8911733,  8035123,  4855475,  2226494, 10448630,
        2041328,   532211, 10049766,  7320606,  7783187, 11536583,
        9192742,  8965808,  7750786,  2462038,   111935,  4306882,
       11193228])],
       [4,
        array([11406300,  9947761,  2539951,  1928472,  1286647,  1360522,
        9680046,  1304518,  2577907,  5903319,  6304940,  8249558,
       11156695,  5704721,  9753227,   465481,  8849435,  5040956,
        8124190, 11094867,  9225419, 10531161,  3796335,  6660230,
         823696,  3271428,  9167574])],
       [5, array([3535672, 9474011, 4708696, 9700618, 4762633])],
       [6,
        array([ 1352149,  6408648,  3218823,   977256,  2488662,   603435,
        6576555,  2555278,  5487362, 10008975,  5066785,  5294573,
        1381729])],
       [7,
        array([ 7078697,  2981709,  2426786,   676729,  2688166,  3353437,
        7244406,  7804172,  9142652, 10594869,    95474,  3867698,
        6645756,  1936281,  3728779, 10800050,  8270358,  2336174,
        6785259,  7282204,  7485619,  8041965,  2445126,  5681877,
        8383953,  9431775, 11442616,  9835489,  3940227,  1289543,
          87876,  6148249,  3026723,  1651607,  4135482,   916739,
       10408908,  9178863, 11775813,  1652898,  1190197,  1913270,
        3759101,  7491500,  5183607,  8476053,  8482428, 11354398,
        2370455,  6820229,  3952122,  9633865,  4498499,  1475415,
       11303906,  2958509, 10639369])],
       [8,
        array([   67999,  3847504,  8303130,   748628,  1321792,  3453436,
        2813805,  6915028,  8459024, 10499123,  8855154,  9783163,
        8580897,  3092270,  3438170,  9067374, 11068581,  4926186,
        6137797,  2207028,  2806970,  8601327,  5183768, 10655752,
        2775719,  6653472,  3995496,  2488194,  3610797,  5508794,
        6524258,  2368954,     2070,  9522863,  1765121,  7842059,
       11473248,  3077500,   130699,  1407101,  2434487,  1129155,
        5643519,  7780188])],
       [9, array([8528119, 6930255,  630592, 5476242])]], dtype=object)
```

However, when I tried to save it, my enviroment crashed because I ran out of memory. I later learned that numpy is optimized for fixed length rows, so as you can see the overall dtype becomes an object, which is not computationally optimal for numpy arrays, and which is probably guessing my enviroment (Google Colaboratory) to crash.

I have also tried it where the second component is a list instead of an array, and that actually is able to save to a .npy file using `numpy.save`. However, when I tried to load the file, it crashes again.

As far as I have searched, there is no computationally optimized way to save such data in one numpy variable. So it looks like I have to save the first column (containing the single ints) in one numpy array. And then for each of those ints, there is another array of numbers that I have to save separately in that particular order, while optimizing the RAM for that process.

Comment: You might try leaving the outer type as a `list` instead of an `array`.

Comment: so it would be a big list of two components, the first being a int, the other being a list or array of the ints?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Keep the `array` for the inner component.

Comment: and then save this using python pickle?

Comment: Not sure on the best way to save it, but that wasn't part of your question.